# How do I change the name of the ASPNETUsers table to User?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using the default authentication system created by ASP.NET Core, and I'd like to know ?

1. how to change the name of the `ASPNETUsers` table to `User` ?
2. How to add the following property to the table: `public string DisplayName {get; set;}`
3. How to add the `RemoteAttribute` attribute to the Email property
4. Is it a good idea to create another table, named Profile, with a one-to-one relationship with the ASPNETUsers table, if I have a few properties ?

thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do those as shown below.

**1.**

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
       base.OnModelCreating(builder);

       builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
          {
              entity.ToTable(name:"User");
           });
   }
```

**2.**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    ......................
    ......................
    public string DisplayName {get; set;}
}
```

**3.** I would like to suggest you to put that on your `ViewModel` instead of the `Core model (i.e. ApplicationUser )` as shown below.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Remote("Foo", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Remote validation is working for you")]
    public string Email { get; set; }


}
```

**4.** Hence you have only few properties,you can keep those properties inside the `ASPNETUsers` table itself. Which is easy to maintain :)